# overide Struts 2 error messages for file upload interceptor

Tags: java, struts2, struts

```
<action name="upload" class="uploadManualAction">
           <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">20971520</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">
                    application/pdf
                </param>
           </interceptor-ref>
           <interceptor-ref name="logFilterStack"></interceptor-ref>
           <result name="success">/jsp/confirmManualUpload.jsp</result>
           <result name="error">/error/manualUploadError.jsp</result>
           <result name="input">/jsp/manualUpload.jsp</result> 
        </action>

this is the first action.





<action name="csvUploadAction" class="csvUploadAction" method="processReadCsv">
         <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">20971520</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">
                    text/csv
                </param>
           </interceptor-ref>
           <interceptor-ref name="logFilterStack"></interceptor-ref>

            <result name="success">/jsp/csvUpload.jsp</result>
             <result name="error">/error/manualUploadError.jsp</result>
             <result name="input">/jsp/csvUpload.jsp</result> 
        </action>

This is the second acton 


i want to overide
```

struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed=Only PDF content is allowed
    struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed=Only CSV content is allowed this messages according 
to the action

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700877/573032

Comment: @RomanC sir Thank you for your answer. But I am looking for an override default struts message. I am done with it. I wrote a new Interceptor to override default messages as per our action  call.

Answer (score 0):

public class CsvFileUploadInterceptor extends FileUploadInterceptor {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CsvFileUploadInterceptor.class);

@Override
protected String getTextMessage(Object action, String messageKey, String[] args) {
    String actionName = action.getClass().getName();
    if (actionName.endsWith(WebAppConst.CSV_UPLOAD_ACTION)) {
        if (messageKey.equals(WebAppConst.STRUTS_MESSAGES_ERROR_FILE_TOO_LARGE)) {
            messageKey = WebAppConst.CSV_UPLOAD_ERROR_FILE_TOO_LARGE;
        } else if (messageKey.equals(WebAppConst.STRUTS_MESSAGES_ERROR_CONTENT_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED)) {
            messageKey = WebAppConst.CSV_UPLOAD_ERROR_CONTENT_TYPE_NOT_ALLOWED;
        }
    }
    return super.getTextMessage(actionName, messageKey, args);

}
```

}